# new Date with setDate gives NaN

Tags: javascript, date

Why does this `new Date().setDate(12)` returns `1510501854723` ?

I'm trying to get first day of the week like that

```
new Date(daterefStart.setDate(daterefStart.getDate() - daterefStart.getDay())).getDate();
```

Where `daterefStart` lets say is today. `daterefStart.getDate() - daterefStart.getDay()` returns `12` which when `setDate` is called it returns weird numbers.

When i first initialize my calendar widget i use exact same function to get the first day of the week and it **works**. What's wrong?

Comment: Well it returns epoch time (in milliseconds) ...

Comment: The `.setDate()` method is for setting the day of the month. Thus `.setDate(12)` will update the object in that way; it *might* set the day of week to 1, or it might not, depending on the realities of the calendar. The return value of the method is the underlying epochal timestamp.

Comment: Why does the title say it returns `NaN`, but the question says `1510501854723`?

Comment: @Barmar because i get NaN when i use getDate ().

Comment: I just tried it and I got `29`.

Comment: I started with `daterefStart = new Date;` to get today's date.